# Parsing data from xls and added to a data grid view using c#

Tags: c#, excel, parsing

I am trying to read a folder that contain a number of xls files (27) and i need to read only 3 specific columns after 21 row e.g. A21,: B21,: ... In a new column a would like to have just the sum of the previous columns. I am thinking to insert a database grid and to insert there the parsing data. My problem is that i have never try to read something from xls. Do you have any ideas. Thanks in advance! (All the data are in the same workshhet in all workbooks)

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel Take a look in this site. There's an example that show you how to read data in excel file

Comment: Do a quick Search in SO there are so many examples using `OLEDB`

Comment: Also see this NON SO link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ankurmee/import-data-from-excel-to-datagridview-in-C-Sharp/